# Passing PHP variables in $wpdb query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I've a table in my database named `wp_q33uds_campaign`. I have a query in my application as follows:

```
$usr = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT user_id FROM wp_q33uds_campaign WHERE date1 = 1451546940');
```

Now, this query returns a `user_id` from the table which has the `date1` column set as `1451546940`.

Now, somewhere in my application, I have a variable named `$dd` where `$dd` is set as `1451546940`. However, when I modify my above query as follows:

```
$usr = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT user_id FROM wp_q33uds_campaign WHERE date1 = $dd);
```

it returns a `NULL` value. What seems to be wrong here? Is there no way to pass in PHP variables inside `$wpdb` query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `$wpdb->prepare()` method to properly escape variables to prevent syntax errors and most importantly to protect against SQL injection attacks - see [Running General Queries](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples_9) in the WordPress documentation. You should also use the `$wpdb->prefix` property to ensure the proper table prefix in your queries.

The value you see for your date is actually a Unix timestamp, you will need to convert this to a string using `date()`;

```
// convert from timestamp to date string
$dd = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 1451546940 );
// your SQL statement with db table prefix and %s placeholder
$sql = "SELECT user_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}campaign WHERE date1 = %s";
// populate vars and run query
$usr = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $dd ) );
```

Answer (score -1):

Use either

```
$usr = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_id FROM wp_q33uds_campaign WHERE date1 = '$dd'");
```

or

```
$usr = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT user_id FROM wp_q33uds_campaign WHERE date1 = \''.$dd.'\'');
```

Comment: This is something you should *never* do. Asking for a SQL injection.

Answer (score -1):

First, you are missing the close quote.

Second, when you use single quotes PHP take the string inside literal, so your $dd is not used as variable is used as string.

There are a lot of ways to fix this.

```
$usr = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT user_id FROM wp_q33uds_campaign WHERE date1 = $dd");
```

Or

```
$usr = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT user_id FROM wp_q33uds_campaign WHERE date1 = ' . $dd);
```

The best way is using the `sprintf` http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

```
$sql = sprintf( 'SELECT user_id FROM wp_q33uds_campaign WHERE date1=%s', $dd);
$usr = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
```

Comment: You should use `$wpdb->prepare()`, not `sprintf()`.

Comment: Never do this, even with server generated variables. You're just asking for trouble and SQL Injection. Get into the habit of using prepared statements for all variables, user supplied or not.

Answer (score -2):

If you want your PHP var to be evaluated, you need to use doublequotes. Otherwise you need to concat your var with your string like this

```
$usr = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT user_id FROM wp_q33uds_campaign WHERE date1 = ' . $dd);
```

Comment: This is asking for a SQL injection.